# Infinitely many solutions of the equation $\frac{x+1}{y}+\frac{y+1}{x} = 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, fractions, pell-type-equations, vieta-jumping

Prove that there exists infinitely many positive integer solutions in $(x,y)$ to the equation :
$$\frac{x+1}{y} + \frac{y+1}{x} = 4$$

Comment: If $(x,y)=(a,b)$ is a solution, then $(x,y)=(4a-1-b,a)$ is a solution.  Starting from a solution $(x,y)=(1,1)$, you get $(x,y)=(2,1)$, $(6,2)$, $\ldots$.

Comment: @Batominovski how did you reach the solution?

Comment: Keyword: Vieta jumping.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping.

Comment: $\dfrac{x+1}{y}+\dfrac{y+1}{x} = 4\implies (6 x - 3)^2 - 3 (4 x - 2 y - 1)^2 = 6$

Comment: @DmitryEzhov how does this help?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046790___
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046791__
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046841___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x+1}{y} + \frac{y+1}{x} = 4$$

$$x^2+x+y^2+y=4xy$$

$$(x+y)^2+(x+y)=6xy$$

Let $X=x+y$ and $Y=x-y$.  Then $X^2+X=\dfrac32\left(X^2-Y^2\right)$ or $(X-1)^2-3Y^2=1$.

That's a [Pell equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html), which has infinitely many solutions:

$X-1=$[$1,2,7,26,97,...$](http://oeis.org/A001075) and $Y=$[$0,1,4,15,56,...$](http://oeis.org/A001353).

Click on the blue numbers to see more.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: how did u get the solution to the Pell's equation

Comment: You'll see recurrence relations at the links I gave to The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences